# how can I get higer privilages on linux

Tags: linux, sudo, privileges

I would like to get higher privilages on my linux computer (I dont have any admin privilages and cant use sudo/su).I would like to get privileges of a root and privileges of file owner.

how can I do it besides using an exploit?

thank you

Comment: If you don't have admin privileges and you can use sudo then you are out of luck.  Questions that seeking solutions that require exploits to be used are out of scope here at Superuser.  Request your permissions be changed through the proper procedure for your organization.

Comment: Why don't you have _"administrator privileges"_ on your own computer?

Comment: well, I do a penestration test to my school computer, so my teacher asked me to do so

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're locked out of a machine that you have physical access to and you own...

If it's running GRUB, reboot the system and press `e` to edit the line at the appropriate GRUB boot entry. Press `e` again to edit the kernel line, and append `init=/bin/bash` at the end. Press `b` to boot, and you will drop into a shell as root. The filesystem will boot as readonly, so you'll need to remount it as read/write with `mount -n -o remount,rw /`. Now you could make any changes that you need to as root, or reset the password with `passwd`.

Alternatively (if no GRUB), you could boot a live Linux CD or USB and enter a chroot session.

Comment: Why not single user mode?

Comment: what do you mean?